# How can I get status of geocoding with Json format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3

I want to fetch the status of the geocode in which I have passed latitude and longitude.

```
String address = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=44.4647452,7.3553838";
  var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(address);

  String add = Regex.Match(json, @"(?s)""formatted_address""\s*:\s*""(.+?)""").Groups[1].Value;
```

From this I can get the address perfectly.

But now I want to get the `status:ok or limit_Exceed`

So how can I perform this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are 3 status you want to catch. They are `ZERO_RESULTS`, `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` and lastly `OK`.

You can use the same query for your formatted_address to search for, and check the status value of your result.

Comment: i have tried that but i didnt get the status.
i have written like : - `Regex.Match(json, @"(?s)""status""\s*:\s*""(.+?)""").Groups[1].Value;`

Comment: how about `Groups[0]`..? `Groups[1]` would get you the 2nd result, which, for status, is empty... (only one statue for one json)